# Error using for loop to handle fetching records from CloudKit query

Tags: swift, for-loop, cloudkit

I am not sure how to handle this error below, this code used to work in my app:

> ERROR: "For-in loop requires 'Result<(matchResults: [(CKRecord.ID, Result<CKRecord, any Error>)], queryCursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?), any Error>' to conform to 'Sequence'"

```
func fetchLocations()
    {
        var locationArray: [CLLocation] = []

        let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "location", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        
        publicDB.fetch(withQuery: query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records) in
            if records != nil{
                for record in records {
                    if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
                        locationArray.append(location)
                    }
                }//end for
            }else {return}
        }//end fetch
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/3856519-fetch):

`records` is actually a `Result` type with signature

```
Result<(matchResults: [(CKRecord.ID, Result<CKRecord, Error>)], queryCursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?), Error>
```

and which is never `nil` by the way.

You have to `switch` over the cases. Something like this

```
publicDB.fetch(withQuery: query, inZoneWith: nil) { result in
      switch result {
           case .success(let matchResults, let queryCursor):
               for matchResult in matchResults {
                   switch matchResult.1 { // the second item in the tuple
                       case .success(let record):
                           if let location = record["location"] as? CLLocation {
                               locationArray.append(location)
                           }
                       case .failure(let error): print(error)
                    } //end 2nd switch 
                } //end for   
           case .failure(let error): print(error)
      }//end 1st switch       
}//end fetch
```

And you have to handle the `queryCursor` for more coming results